# How to use corecursion in c?

Tags: c, corecursion

I need help trying to find where to place the print statements in each function (alpha_count and sum_digits) so that they will only print once (at the end of the program).

Ex.
Number of characters: 8
Sum of digits: 19

As of right now they print each time the function has been called. Any ideas?

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

//Prototypes
void count_alpha(char *s, int len, int index); 
void sum_digit(char *s, int len, int index);

#define SIZE 22

int main(void){
  //Declarations
  char string[SIZE];
  int length;

  //Get string from user
  printf("Enter a string of letters and numbers: ");
  scanf("%s", string);
  printf("String: %s\n", string);
  //Get length of string
  length = strlen(string);
  printf("Length: %d\n", length);
  //Get letters from string
  count_alpha(string, length, 0);

  return 0;
}

void count_alpha(char *s, int len, int index){
  static int characters = 0;
  char c = ' ';

  if (index < len){
    c = s[index];
    if(isalpha(c)){
        characters++;
        printf("char: %d\n", characters);
        index++;
        printf("index: %d\n", index);
        count_alpha(s, len, index);
    }
    else if(isdigit(c)){
        sum_digit(s, len, index);
    }
    //index++;
    //printf("index: %d\n", index);
    //printf("Number of Characters: %d\n", characters);
  }
  //else
  printf("Number of Characters: %d\n", characters);

}

void sum_digit(char *s, int len, int index){
  static int digits = 0;
  char c = ' ';

  if (index < len){
    c = s[index];
    if(isalpha(c)){
        count_alpha(s, len, index);
  }
  else if(isdigit(c)){
        printf("num is: %c", c);
        //printf("number is: %d", (atoi(&s[index])));
        //digits += atoi(&c);
        digits += c - '0';
        printf("sum: %d\n", digits);
        index++;
        printf("index: %d\n", index);
        sum_digit(s, len, index);
    }
    //index++;
    //printf("index: %d\n", index);
    //printf("Sum of digits: %d\n", digits);
  }
  //else
  printf("Sum of digits: %d\n", digits);

}
```

Comment: errr... by keeping global variables and printing them at the end of the program?

Comment: `digits += atoi(&c);` should be `digits += c - '0';`. `atoi` requires a null-terminated string and not the address of a single character.

Comment: @WeatherVane What do you mean keep global variables? What would I be storing in there?

Comment: A static variable in each function that keeps track off how deep the recursion is and only prints on the required level should also work.

Comment: Recommend have `alpha_count()` and `sum_digits()` return their summation.  Let the calling function , `main()` then print.

Comment: @user1320881 would you be able to show me how to write that?

Comment: @chux I tried that, but because main only calls alpha_count, I wasn't sure how to get the sum_digit to return its value back to main.

Comment: This is *mutual* recursion. Corecursion is [pretty different](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `int characters = 0` and `int digits =0` globally, keeping them global will be of same use as of static variables in addition it can be accessed anywhere thus will help you in printing what you wanted just once in main function.

For declaring them global just declare them outside all functions and at start of program.

```
.
.//header files
.
//#include <ctype.h>
int characters = 0;
int digits = 0;
```

In main(): just print them

```
printf("Number of Characters: %d\n", characters);
printf("Sum of digits: %d\n", digits);
```

**EDIT**: Without global variables by using pointers.

```
void count_alpha(char *s, int len, int index,int *charac,int *dig);
void sum_digit(char *s, int len, int index,int *charac,int *dig);
```

In main:

```
int* charac=&characters;
int* dig=&digits;
count_alpha(string,length,0,charac,dig);
```

And whenever you see a function call pass these pointers:

```
count_alpha(string,length,0,charac,dig);
```

For incrementing values just use:

```
(*charac)++;
(*dig)++;
```

Comment: Is there a way to do it without using global variables?

Comment: But main doesn't call sum_digits, it only calls alpha_count. How do I get sum_digits back to main?

Comment: Then you have to pass two variables by reference to both functions from main...Which i can show you if you want..

Comment: References are C++ and not C. So that part is not valid, here.

Comment: @wrangler You've used a non-standard `main()` and references (which don't exist in C).

Comment: @PCLuddite "non standard main()", seriously?  that was just the pseudocode

Comment: C++ is irrelevant to the question. It doesn't make sense to bring it up. Would you answer a C question with a solution in C# or Python as well?

Comment: Thats why i made edit2 and enough of you ,it can happen to anyone i thought both c/c++ are tagged.....If there is problem with the second solution then tell..

Comment: @wrangler There's no problem with "edit2". The problem is that the first edit about C++ exists.

Comment: @wrangler I will insist that it is the problem. The users who hover around the C language tag spend half of their time editing and explaining that C and C++ are separate and distinct languages with different feature sets. Answering a C question with C++ code doesn't help. If you remove the C++ explanation in your answer, I will remove the downvote. That is all I will say on the matter.

Comment: @wrangler I apologize for being curt. For all your trouble, I upvoted your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As `alpha_count()` and `sum_digits()` are effectively doing some statistics gathering, pass in a pointer to a statistics type.  Drop the static variables.

```
typedef struct {
  unsigned characters;
  unsigned digits;
} char_digs;


void sum_digit(char *s, int len, int index, char_digs *stat) {
  // static int digits = 0;
  ...
  count_alpha(s, len, index, stat);
  ...
  stat->digits += c - '0';
  ...
  sum_digit(s, len, index, stat);
  ...
}      

void count_alpha(char *s, int len, int index, char_digs *stat) {
  // like sum_digit() above
}

int main(void) {
  ...
  char_digs stat = {0,0};
  ...
  count_alpha(..., ..., &stat);
  printf("Number of Characters: %u\n", stat.characters);
  printf("Sum of digits: %u\n", stat.digits);
}
```